# Godot some faces of imported from Blender model are darker then other

Tags: blender, models, godot, normals

I tried to export some scene from Blender to Godot as `.fbx`, `.dae` and `.glb`, but every time it has the same problem in Godot: some faces are darker:

[image]

[image]

I remember there was such problem earlier, and it was solving by tweaking some shader parameter, but what it was, I do not remember. It was related to normals, as far as I remember

---

**Update**

I particularly solved the issue, by adding two lines to mud shader (road has another material):

```
// was from beginning 
ALBEDO = color.rgb;
METALLIC = metallic;
ROUGHNESS = roughness;
SPECULAR = specular;
// added this two
NORMALMAP_DEPTH = 1.0;
NORMAL = vec3(1.0,1.0,1.0);
```

However, now when the angle between camera and sun is low, the mud surface becomes too dark, although the road surface, which has another (unchanged) material is still bright:

[image]

And, despite on the fact that most of occurrences of the origin problem with dark faces are gone, still there is area where it is still dark:

[image]

Comment: `NORMAL = vec3(1.0,1.0,1.0)` this does not look like a valid normal. I'd expect something more like (0,0,1)

Comment: @DMGregory almost the same